# Read Nagios Notification using php

Tags: php, nagios

How can I read response from a remote server using Nagios Notification? I'm new to this Nagios Notification System.
The only data from the server side is, they are pushing data in this format:

```
/usr/bin/curl --url http://mywebpage.com/TicKeTREder.php? --data-urlencode "eventType=Nagios Notification" --data-urlencode "message=$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$#$LONGDATETIME$#$SERVICEDESC$#$HOSTALIAS$#$SERVICESTATE$#$SERVICEOUTPUT$#$CONTACTEMAIL$#$NOTIFICATIONISESCALATED$"
```

I've tried searching. But no results found.

What I need is read those tickets from Nagios notification system with my TicKeTREder.php page.

<strike>Is there any plugin to read these data using php.</strike>

Issue solved since the problem was not with the program side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the message with

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
```

You can split the information parts with:

```
$infoArray = explode('#', $message);
```

Then `$infoArray[0]` holds the notification type and so on.

Comment: Not worked for me. url decoding also not worked. I think some Nagios plugin is required.

Comment: @GeoTom What does `print_r($_REQUEST);` output?

Comment: Issue solved. It was due to the monitoring server issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you will get data from nagios as a string where all the server /service details are seprated with hash(#). You can split these details by :

```
$Array = explode('#', $message);
```